# Emacs epa and gnupg2: "no usable configuration"

Tags: emacs, gnupg

Using [Emacs for Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com) 25.1.1 and [gnupg2](http://braumeister.org/formula/gnupg2) 2.0.30 installed via homebrew on macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

Emacs works correctly and gnugp2 also works well on the command line level (email addresses removed):

```
pu@pumbair.local 528 ~/Dropbox/org $  echo "Hello World" >text.txt
pu@pumbair.local 536 ~/Dropbox/org $  gpg -a -e -r x@y <text.txt >text.gpg
pu@pumbair.local 537 ~/Dropbox/org $  gpg -d text.gpg
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
2048-bit RSA key, ID 37B58834, created 2017-01-18 (main key ID 45C04EA8)
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 37B58834, created 2017-01-18
Hello World
```

My ./emacs/init.el says

```
; gpg
(require 'epa-file)
(epa-file-enable)
(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/local/bin/gpg2")
```

and

```
pu@pumbair.local 505 ~/.emacs.d $  file /usr/local/bin/gpg2
/usr/local/bin/gpg2: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

but I cannot seem to get Emacs to use gpg2; `Meta-x epa-list-keys` yields:

```
GPG error: "no usable configuration", OpenPGP
```

I'm using gpg and gpg2 here but the first is a symlink to the latter.

What did I miss?

**EDIT**

Browsing trough EasyPG's source I got the impression that it only worked with gpg2 2.1+ so I uninstalled the homebrew version and installed version 2.1.17 from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/gpgosx/docu/Download/) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So I ended up browsing some source files related to this question and mailed Daiki Ueno directly. He replied quickly, telling me to use `custom-set-variables` instead of `setq`:

```
(require 'epa-file)
(custom-set-variables '(epg-gpg-program  "/usr/local/bin/gpg2"))
(epa-file-enable)
```

I assume this is obvious to Emacs people but I hardly use Emacs for anything else than org-mode, so it wasn't for me.

Comment: As a regular emacs users this is not obvious, and something that is advertised as working out of the box

Comment: Looks like it's a bug we cannot use `setq` and have to resort to `customize`: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24229

Comment: gpg changed folder I think - should now be
    (custom-set-variables '(epg-gpg-program  "/usr/local/bin/gpg"))

Answer (score 3):

`gpg` in only inside `/usr/local/gnupg-2.2/bin`. In Eamcs, `(getenv "Path")` and `exec-path` only contains `/usr/bin`, but new version of macOS restricts the access of `/usr/bin`.

My solution is to create a symbolic link and add the path into the emacs environment and its exec path.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s ../gnupg-2.2/bin/gpg2 gpg
```

Inside `.emacs`

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```